# Swift IOS: Save an instance of a view controller as draft with all gestures

Tags: ios, swift, save, view, gestures

> I have a custom view with UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer
>
> User can keep adding this views in the view controller by using add button.
>
> Entire view controller should be saved as draft, so he can come and edit his stuff when ever he feels

I tried

Method 1 :
Saving this in var and sending back to previous Viewcontroller and getting it back. But when user restarts the app, it goes away.

Method 2 :
I tried saving in UserDefaults.

```
for let TxtBoxVar as UITextField in self.view.subviews
{
    TxtCwtVar+=1
    let TxtDataVar = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(TxtBoxVar)
    DftSdbVal.setObject(TxtDataVar, forKey: "TxtBox\(TxtCwtVar)_Key")
    
}
```

But this is ignoring all gesture of the view while saving. That means user cannot pinch or pan on the views after getting it back using beow method

```
let TxtCwtVal = DftSdbVal.integerForKey("TxtCwtKey")
    for TxtCwtVar in 1...TxtCwtVal
    {
        if let VyuDtaVar = DftSdbVal.objectForKey("TxtBox\(TxtCwtVar)_Key")
        {
            if let VyuVar = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(VyuDtaVar as! NSData) as? UITextField
            {
                self.view.addSubview(VyuVar)
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this or can we store an instance alternatively with gestures ?

Comment: Don't persist the UITextField object.  Persist the necessary information about the text field; it's text, position and size.  Anything else, such as gesture recognisers can simply be recreated as required

Comment: But i do not know, how many text feilds and other fields are there. bcoz user keeps on adding this. So Saving so much info with be tuff

Comment: try Core Data @SujayUN

Comment: Not really.  You can easily persist an array of objects using NSKeyedArchiver and this can be restored using NSKeyedUnArchiver, but Core Data is a better choice